# How to specify the Data types of a column name without any headers in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have text file without any header .
While loading to DF in pandas few columns are loading as float which I want as string .
For files with header I use to specify the Data types as below.
dtype = {"column1"str,"Column2":int} .

How to achieve the above scenario or how to specify the datatypes for data frame without any header names ?

Comment: Did you try using column index instead of column name?
So {0: str, 1:int}

Answer (score 1):

You can use column index.

```py
a = "2,5,'adgh'\n4,2,'sgd'"
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(a), header=None, dtype={0:str, 1:int, 2:str})
print(df.dtypes)
```

output:

```py
0    object
1     int64
2    object
dtype: object
```