# Calculate mean of selected columns with multilevel header

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-level

I have a dataframe with multilevel headers for the columns like this:

```
name   1          2         3        4
       x     y    x    y    x    y   x   y
A      1     4    3    7    2    1   5   2
B      2     2    6    1    4    5   1   7
```

How can I calculate the mean for 1x, 2x and 3x, but not 4x?
I tried:

```
df['mean']= df[('1','x'),('2','x'),('3','x')].mean()
```

This did not work, it syas key error. I would like to get:

```
name   1          2         3        4     mean
       x     y    x    y    x    y   x   y  
A      1     4    3    7    2    1   5   2   2
B      2     2    6    1    4    5   1   7   4
```

Is there a way to calculate the mean while keeping the first column header as an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *only one* solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

iterables = [[1, 2, 3, 4], ["x", "y"]]
array = [
    [1, 4, 3, 7, 2, 1, 5, 2],
    [2, 2, 6, 1, 4, 5, 1, 7]
]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables)
df = pd.DataFrame(array,  index=["A", "B"], columns=index)

df["mean"] = df.xs("x", level=1, axis=1).loc[:,1:3].mean(axis=1)

print(df)

   1     2     3     4    mean
   x  y  x  y  x  y  x  y     
A  1  4  3  7  2  1  5  2  2.0
B  2  2  6  1  4  5  1  7  4.0
```

**Steps:**

1. Select all the "x"-columns with `df.xs("x", level=1, axis=1)`
2. Select only columns 1 to 3 with `.loc[:,1:3]`
3. Calculate the mean value with `.mean(axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you so much! It says: TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [1] of <class 'int'>. Indeed the 1,2,3 are integers

Comment: Sorry, but than your index 1,2,3 are no integers! Change `.loc[:,1:3]` to `.loc[:,"1":"3"]`

Comment: After this adaptation, I get : TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str().  The column headers should be integers, I imported them from excel where there are integers. How could I check and change the data type of the column header (not the data type within the column, those are floats in my real dataset)

Comment: Please add a running minimal example as I did in my answer post. I need more information about how you load the data. You can setup the column names like [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45314/dataframe-has-no-column-names-how-to-add-a-header) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756326/how-to-specify-the-data-types-of-a-column-name-without-any-headers-in-pandas-dat)

Comment: I tried to add a running example, but I found out that the problem was in importing excel file (which I cannot share here). There were both integers and strings as header. When I removed all strings, the previous code did work. I will work out how to import the data with the string-headers and integer-headers separately and then fuse the dataframes afterwards. That should do the trick!